# Compressing folder into 7z in java

Tags: java, compression, directory, 7zip, lzma

I want to compress a folder into .7z extension using java. Iam trying using the below code but it is creating a new file and appending all the source files content into one single file. Can anyone please help me to be out of this problem.....

```
Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
encoder.SetAlgorithm(2);
encoder.SetDictionarySize(8388608);
encoder.SetNumFastBytes(128);
encoder.SetMatchFinder(1);
encoder.SetLcLpPb(3,0,2);
encoder.SetEndMarkerMode(false);
encoder.WriteCoderProperties(outStream);
long fileSize;
fileSize = inputToCompress.length();
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)                                     
{
        outStream.write((int)(fileSize >>> (8 * i)) & 0xFF);
}                               

encoder.Code(inStream, outStream, -1, -1, null);
```

Comment: Don't you want the files in that folder to be added into a single .7z file? Btw, there's a lot of information missing, e.g. how you handle multiple files.

Comment: I suggest you use [Apache Commons Compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/examples.html#a7z). It offer more support than LZMA SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, compress the directory with tar. After that compress this file using your current code.